# Dynamic Nested Form link_to_add called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-form-for

I am using ryan bates nested_form gem to dynamically add some nested field to a form.

e.g.

```
<%= f.fields_for :phones do |phone_form| %>
<%= phone_form.text_field :phone_number %>
<% end %>
<%= f.link_to_add "Add a phone", :phones %></p>
```

Everything works, except TWO empty fields are added every time the link is clicked.

I placed a breakpoint on  `$('form a.add_nested_fields').live('click', function()`  and see it is called twice...

I am using chrome on a mac

Comment: could you show the html which is generated and more of the javascript please

Answer (score 9):

Look in your header. You'll see that this is in there twice:

```
<script src="/assets/nested_form.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Just remove the second reference (perhaps in your application.html.erb) and it will work.

Comment: To elaborate further, this is probably caused by this line in your layout:<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "nested_forms.js" %>
Remove the specific nested_forms.js reference since it will already be included by the application reference.

Comment: Ok and what if i dont want any Blank items ,, i just need to add them if the user clics .. =( i cant figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

you may have nested form js files being loaded twice

Answer (score 1):

For those having this issue using rails 4 / turbolinks and not finding nested_form.js included twice, try removing turbolinks from application.js. Once I did this and bounced the server this issue was resolved.

Credit here: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/issues/307

Answer (score -1):

check for loading js files more than one and make sure to clear you browser cache if you work in multiply projects